# Dark theme for Plotly Dashboard in Python

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have made a dashboard in Plotly Dash and now I am looking for ways how to implement a dark-theme layout according to a customised design provided to me. I haven't used Dash Bootstrap Components so implementing that is not an answer. Is there any way I can apply a dark theme, ideally through the click of a button in the callback, to render another customised css for dark-theme? I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Can [Plotly Dash: How to change the button color when it is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62079486/plotly-dash-how-to-change-the-button-color-when-it-is-clicked) help you?

Comment: It can, and I have seen many examples where we can return the "style" component property. But what I am looking for is to return "className" in the callback. Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

So I got the answer. If you want to callback a css class which you have defined in the assets folder, you just have to mention it in the callback like that:

```
@app.callback(
Output(component_id='color-change', component_property='className'),
Input(component_id='drop-color', component_property='value'))


def update_output_div(input_value):
if input_value=='B':
    return 'black'

else:
    return 'red'
```